# Recompile 20.04 HWE kernel?

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I am trying to rebuild the 20.04 HWE kernel 5.8 since I need to change one config option. I am trying to guess my way through this since most of the info on rebuilding kernels on Ubuntu seems to be antiquated.

What I do:

```
apt source linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
cd linux-meta-hwe-5.8-5.8.0.40.45~20.04.25/
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

This eventually fails:

```
dh_gencontrol -a -- -Vkernel-version=5.8.0 -Vkernel-abi-version=5.8.0-40 -Vdkms:zfs-modules="zfs-modules (= )," -Vdkms:virtualbox-guest-modules="virtualbox-guest-modules (= 5.8.0-40)," -Vdkms:wireguard-linux-compat-modules="wireguard-modules (= 1.0.0),"
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: can't parse dependency zfs-modules (= )
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: can't parse dependency zfs-modules (= )
dpkg-gencontrol: error: error occurred while parsing Provides field: zfs-modules (= ), virtualbox-guest-modules (= 5.8.0-40), wireguard-modules (= 1.0.0),
dh_gencontrol: error: dpkg-gencontrol -plinux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 -ldebian/changelog -Tdebian/linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04.substvars -Pdebian/linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 -UMulti-Arch -Vkernel-version=5.8.0 -Vkernel-abi-version=5.8.0-40 "-Vdkms:zfs-modules=zfs-modules (= )," "-Vdkms:virtualbox-guest-modules=virtualbox-guest-modules (= 5.8.0-40)," "-Vdkms:wireguard-linux-compat-modules=wireguard-modules (= 1.0.0)," returned exit code 255
dh_gencontrol: error: Aborting due to earlier error
make: *** [debian/rules:101: binary-arch] Error 2
```

I don't care about vbox or ZFS so I am happy to disable those somehow, and wireguard is part of 5.8.

I have successfully rebuilt the standard 5.4 Ubuntu kernel, so this is a specific HWE issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` is a meta package, It doesn't contain linux source`.

Comment: Sure, that seems to be the case, but which one does, then? For the stock Ubuntu kernel I can just get the source with `apt source linux` and it unpacks it into `linux-5.4.0`, but not so for the HWE kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone the repo:

   ```
    git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal
   ```
2. Checkout the branch:

   ```
    cd focal
    git checkout origin/hwe-5.8
   ```

If you want to disable the nvidia driver, add this patch:

```
diff --git a/debian/rules b/debian/rules
index 8c3c71a..8742713 100755
--- a/debian/rules
+++ b/debian/rules
@@ -100,6 +100,8 @@ ifeq ($(do_mainline_build),true)
        skipretpoline=true
 endif
 
+do_dkms_nvidia=false
+
 # Disable tools build and packaging if do_tools != true
 ifneq ($(do_tools),true)
        do_linux_tools=
```

3. Install the build dependencies:

   ```
    sudo apt-get build-dep linux
   ```
4. Build the kernel:

   ```
    fakeroot debian/rules clean
    fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
   ```

Comment: This is another good way to get the source. I don't think that `debian/rules build` does anything useful.

Comment: debian/rules build builds it faster, trust me, as a member of the kernel team I do this regularly. :-)

Comment: But I see no use to run it before `debian/rules binary`. I am building kernels a lot too.

Comment: when building on system with many multiple CPUs fakeroot will produce contention on a lock and this slows down the build, so using debian/rules build without fakeroot removes that contention :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, those got me quite far! However, there is one last remaining problem: The above tries to also build all Nvidia kernel modules for various versions of the driver, and eventually fails because it cannot fetch some sources. Can I specify a different argument than `binary-headers binary-generic` which does not include all the Nvidia stuff?

Comment: you can set do_dkms_nvidia=false in the debian/rules file to force the Nvidia driver to no longer build, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile a linux 5.8 kernel on Ubuntu 20.04, the package source to download is `linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)`.

Run

```
apt source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

then compile the kernel. You'll find the source in `linux-hwe-5.8-5.8.0` directory.

The command will download the source of the currently used kernel. If you are using another kernel, e.g. 5.4, you can manually add the version, like

```
apt source linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-40-generic
```